# Is there a pitfall to using two Hikari connection pools pointing to the same db?

Tags: spring-boot, datasource, log4j2, connection-pooling, hikaricp

In a Spring Boot application using Log4j2, I have setup a DataSource via yaml-configuration. But since Log4j2 needs a connection pool already in the startup phase for its JDBC Appender, a second data source must be provided separately. This results in the application having two connection pools running, both writing to the same database.

### My first question is:

Are there any concerns about this setup, or is this the normal approach anyway?

Alternatively, the following setup would come to mind: we programmatically initialize the DataSource, so that we  have access to it. Further on, we can then programmatically extend the existing Log4j2 configuration that doesn't have a JDBC Appender yet. By doing so we can pass the pooled DataSource that we also use for the application itself.

### My second question is therefore:

Are there any caveats to using the same DataSource for both the application and the Log4j2 logging framework?

**Many thanks for any information that helps to clarify the situation.**